# What is the grammatical name of structure of "having cleaned"?

Tags: grammar

I met the using of "having cleaned" while I didn't meet this kind of using before and I would like to know what is the name of this structure in English grammar, in order to read and to get more information about it.

The full sentence is:

"So if you cannot reduce the patient's shivering for any reason, you can't get rid of any artefact despite **having cleaned** the skin, optimised your position, patient comfort, made sure your patient is as warm as they can be, but in circumstances it's not always possible to reduce all disturbances to a normal ECG.In that case, you could use to filter button."

Comment: It's a [perfect participle](http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-participle)

Comment: It's also two *very* bad sentences; the first  is an unintelligible sequence of phrases and clauses whose syntactic relationships are wholly incoherent, and the second is unidiomatic. *Despite having cleaned the skin*, however, is internally well-formed, so the question itself is answerable.

Comment: It is a dreadful garbled sentence. Nevertheless _despite having cleaned the skin_ can be analysed as a preposition phrase with an embedded gerund-participle clause functioning as a concessive adjunct.

Answer (score 6):

*Having cleaned* may be called a *gerund-participial perfect*—the gerund or present-participle form of the perfect construction *HAVE cleaned*. The perfect construction may be conjugated with infinitive and gerund-participle forms of *HAVE* as well as with the finite forms (*have, has, had*) with which you are probably more familiar.

> INFINITIVE:                     She wants him **to have cleaned** the skin by the time she returns.
>   GERUND-PARTICIPLE: **Having cleaned** the skin, you may proceed to applying the electrodes.

Traditional grammar distinguishes between ***gerund*** and ***present participle*** uses of the *-ing* form: the term *gerund* is used when the form acts as a noun and the term *present participle* is used when it acts as an adjective or as a component of the progressive construction. In your example, *having cleaned the skin* acts as the object of the preposition *despite*, so *having cleaned* is parsed as noun-like and traditional grammar calls this use a ***gerund*** perfect or something similar.

This distinction is of dubious value, since **a)** the adjectival or nominal quality of the *-ing* form often (perhaps usually) coexists with some degree of verbal quality, **b)** that adjectival or nominal quality is often ascribable only to the phrase or clause which the *-ing* form heads, not the *-ing* form in isolation, and **c)** there is no evident reason why progressive and uncontroversially clausal uses of the form should be categorized as adjectival participles rather than nominal gerunds.

Consequently, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* calls the *-ing* form a ‘gerund-participle’ in all its uses. It’s an awkward name, but it preserves some continuity with traditional terminology without conceding anything to traditional analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is the function of such use, or what is difference between saying  "Despite having cleaned the skin optimize etc" and "Despite (of) cleaning the skin optimize etc."?

Comment: +1 I think this construction can also be used instead of a clause if we want to emphasize that an event takes place  before the other one and both actions happened in the past: Having broken my leg I did not play any longer. (After I had broken my leg I did not play any longer).

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent *Having cleaned* is explicitly perfective--"Even after you have cleaned the skin." Beyond that, I'm afraid that when you get outside *Despite having cleaned the skin* the sentence collapses into total incoherence.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent: Please check my answer below

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't think "Having cleaned the skin, you may proceed to applying the electrodes" is **GERUND-PARTICIPLE**. It is **PAST PARTICIPLE**

Comment: @TranLeNguyen Do you have any citation to confirm it's a past participle? Even your own answer says it's gerund.

Comment: http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/participles_form.htm

Comment: @user178049: Instead of using a clause, we can use present participle or past participle to join with another clause. Now, we have the preposition "despite". After preposition, we must use a noun, a noun phrase or a gerund

Comment: @TranLeNguyen *cleaned* is a 'past participle', required as a component of the perfect construction, but the head of the verb group, *having*, which determines the character of the clause it heads, is a gerund-participle. And in contemporary grammatical analysis clauses may also be the object of prepositions; we no longer adhere to the artificial distinction of prepositions and 'subordinating conjunctions'.

Comment: @StoneyB: As far as I know, the present participle is used to express actions happened at the same time and no "having" word here (Eg: Going to school, I met him). But past participle, we must use "having" word (Eg: Having done all my exercises, I went to school). That is because the action in "having" phrase happened before the action in remaining clause

Answer (score 1):

Normally, "having cleaned" can be past participle or a gerund, but "having cleaned" in your sentence is the gerund

"despite" is the preposition. So, we must have gerund form after "despite"

Back to the question, why do we use "despite having cleaned", not "despite cleaning"?

The sentence using "despite" can divide into 2 parts:

- Main clause
- "despite" clause

For example:

Despite being poor, he learns very well.

"Despite" clause-------main clause

Both forms "despite having cleaned" and "despite cleaning" are correct but different situation.

1. "despite + Gerund (V-ing)": express the action occurring at the same time as main clause. For example:

   - Despite being poor, he learns very well. (we can understand this sentence as following: He is poor. He learns very well.)
   - Despite eating a lot, she still felt hungry yesterday. (we can understand this sentence as following: she ate a lot. She still felt hungry yesterday.)
2. "Despite + having + past participle": express the action occurred before the main clause. For example:

   - Despite having learned a lot, he cannot answer that question. (we can understand this sentence as following: He learned a lot. He cannot answer that question.)
   - Despite having not stolen the camera, she was still arrested yesterday. (we can understand this sentence as following: She had not stolen the camera. She was still arrested yesterday.)

For the passive voice, it still belongs to 2 parts above ("Despite + Gerund (V-ing)" and "Despite + having + past participle"). At this time, the formula is a little bit change:

> "Despite + being + past participle": express the passive action occurring at the same time as main clause.
>
> "Despite + having + been + past participle": express the passive action occurred before the main clause.